# cat files in subdirectories using linux commands

Tags: linux, cat

I have the following directories:

```
P922_101
P922_102
.
.
```

Each directory, for instance P922_101 has following subdirectories:

```
140311_AH8MHGADXX  140401_AH8CU4ADXX
```

Each subdirectory, for instance 140311_AH8MHGADXX has the following files:

```
1_140311_AH8MH_P922_101_1.fastq.gz  1_140311_AH8MH_P922_101_2.fastq.gz    
2_140311_AH8MH_P922_101_1.fastq.gz  2_140311_AH8MH_P922_101_2.fastq.gz
```

And files in 140401_AH8CU4ADXX are:

```
1_140401_AH8CU_P922_101_1.fastq.gz  1_140401_AH8CU_P922_4001_2.fastq.gz        
2_140401_AH8CU_P922_101_1.fastq.gz  2_140401_AH8CU_P922_4001_2.fastq.gz
```

I want to do 'cat' for the files in the subdirectories in the following way:

```
cat 1_140311_AH8MH_P922_101_1.fastq.gz 2_140311_AH8MH_P922_101_1.fastq.gz
1_140401_AH8CU_P922_101_1.fastq.gz 2_140401_AH8CU_P922_101_1.fastq.gz > P922_101_1.fastq.gz
```

which means that files ending with _1.fastq.gz should be concatenated into a single file and files ending with _2.fatsq.gz into another file.

It should be run for all files in subdirectories in all directories. Could someone give a linux solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` for this:

```
find /top/path -mindepth 2 -type f -name "*_1.fastq.gz" -exec cat {} \; > one_file
find /top/path -mindepth 2 -type f -name "*_2.fastq.gz" -exec cat {} \; > another_file
```

This will look for all the files starting from `/top/path` and having a name matching the pattern `_1.fastq.gz` / `_2.fastq.gz` and `cat` them into the desired file. `-mindepth 2` makes `find` look for files that are at least under the current directory; this way, files in `/top/path` won't be matched.

Note that you will probably need `zcat` instead of `cat`, for `gz` files.

---

As you keep adding details in comments, let's see what else we can do:

Say you have the list of directories in a file `directories_list`, each line containing one:

```
while read directory
do
   find $directory -mindepth 2 -type f -name "*_1.fastq.gz" -exec cat {} \; > $directory/output
done < directories_list
```

Comment: thanks!! is it possible to print which files are concatenated? just to make sure everything is going correct.

Comment: @user1779730 doing `find /top/path -type f -name "*_1.fastq.gz"` alone will give you the names of the files.

Comment: In the above example, the files only in the subdirectories of the root directory should be concatenated. Which mean concatenation is independent of the root directory.

Comment: @user1779730 I see. Using `-mindepth 2` should make. See my update.

Comment: Even -mindepth seems to do the same task as before. In the initial post, P922_101 and P922_102 are the main directories. Each of these main directories have subdirectories with files. The files in subirectories of P922_101 should be concatenated to the main directory P922_101, and the files in subdirectories of P922_102 should be concatenated into main directory P922_102.

Comment: @user1779730 then use full paths on everything: `find /path/of/dir1 -mindepth 2 .... -exec cat {} \; > /path/of/dir1/output1` and the same with path2.

Comment: Thank you. But i have hundred of such directories and it would be cumbersome to do for all by specifying the path. Could you suggest a better way?

Comment: @user1779730 see update. Try to do some research and give all the details before hand. It is quite tiring to get more and more conditions after the question was formulated.

Comment: @user1779730 so what did you end up doing? Remember you can accept an answer if you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Since they're compressed, you should probably use `gzip -dc` (decompress and write to stdout) -

```
find /somePath -type f -name "*.fastq.gz" -exec gzip -dc {} \; | \
    tee -a /someOutFolder/out.txt
```

Comment: `zcat` should suffice, so that you don't need to decompress.

Comment: @fedorqui uncompress to stdout is equivalent to `zcat`. The system I tested on didn't have zcat.